# Studying the hyperboloid model, what is represented by the conic sections?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I am trying to get my head around the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic geometry.

[Hyperboloid_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model)

The article is much too technical for me, please improve.

And was thinking the hyperboloid $ x^2 +y^2 - z^2= -1: z >0 $ 
has as asymptotic cone $  x^2 +y^2 - z^2= 0: z >0 $

And with cones you have conic sections

[ConicSection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)

Then I got puzzled what hyperbolic item is represented for each conic section, came to the following list:

*Conic section -> Hyperbolic item*

- circle -> circle centered at (0,0,1)
- ellipse -> circle not centered at (0,0,1 )
- parabola -> horocycle
- hyperbola (one half) plane through (0,0,0) (euclidean point) -> hyperbolic line
- hyperbola (one half) plane not through (0,0,0) (euclidean point) -> hypercycle

Is this list correct? Are there  possible additions?

Comment: Not sure about elipses. I though circles were represented as circles. This may be different for conic section of hyperboloïd.

Comment: All the statements on your list are correct.

Comment: Hi @Willamein I made a few minor edits, Hope ok, Else please feel free to roll back.

Comment: @narasimham why should I roll back a good edit